# html2Canvas image border radius - img vs class css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using html2Canvas library version 0.4. In one particular case, I am trying to add border radius to an image. This works if I add this to the CSS:

```
img{
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

But instead if I specify a class with same properties, and add that class to the image, then the border radius is not respected. I want this to work because not all images need the border radius.

Here is [an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdb1hfay/2/). **Please click "Run"** first, so the image is loaded.

The actual code JavaScript library is copied in the JavaScript section of the fiddle. Can someone help with where is this happening inside the JavaScript so I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you create your image you don't specify a class, try adding this line before you append the image to your div :

```
img.className = "ab";
```

Comment: Unfortunately the issue happens way before the append. By the time append is called, damage is already done. It is not about a css property in the final result. It is about how the border-radius property is handled during the processing.